# Inheritance from two unchangable headers

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say that I have two classes:

```
public class1() {
    ...
}

public class2() : public class1 {
    ...
}
```

These two classes are not changeable - they come with a library.

Say that I want to now have two classes that inherit from these classes:

- `class3` inherits from `class1`
- `class4` inherits from `class2`

However, for `class4`, is it possible to, instead of indirectly inheriting from `class1`, inherit from `class3` instead, seeing as `class3` inherits from `class1`?

Comment: Of course it's possible. The question is whether or not that makes sense semantically.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I'm not sure what "makes sense semantically" means. Could you please tell me what you mean by that? Thanks :)

Comment: It is possible for class4 to derive from class3 yes... whether that's what you want, only you can tell

Comment: Inheritance is meant to express a certain relation between the concepts that your classes represents.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to inherit from QVariantAnimation and QPropertyAnimation to override and add a few methods that will be used in most of my apps. Because QPropertyAnimation inherits from QVariantAnimation I think I need to also inherit my implementation of QPropertyAnimation from my implementation of QVariantAnimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not deriving class4 from class2 and instead replicating the functions of class2 on class4. It seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It may not be a good idea though - do you need just the functionality of `class1` or do you also need what `class3` provides? If not, then there is no reason to drag all of `class3` into your new class.

Comment: Yes, i do need everything that class3 provides.